# braces around params -- why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I ran across this in a tutorial:

```
const Todos = ({todos}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    {todos.map(todo => <p key={todo}>{todo}</p>)}
  </div>
)
```

Why does parameter have braces around it? If I'd written it myself, the first line would look like this:

```
const Todos = (todos) => (...
```

Is this some wacky new ES6 syntax that I simply can't find documented?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curly Brakets in Es2015](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35190064/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the syntax for **parameter object destructuring**, which was introduced as part of ECMAScript 2015. The `Todos` function doesn't define a single parameter named `todos`, but instead accesses the `todos` property of an object that's passed in (and that is immediately destructured).

It is roughly equivalent to the following version:

```
const Todos = (_param) => {
  let todos = _param.todos;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      {todos.map(todo => <p key={todo}>{todo}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Check out [Destructuring and parameter handling](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) for more information on destructuring.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer and the link! I'll definitely be reading more 2ality :)

Comment: You should. ;) If this answer helped solve your problem, please accept it as the correct answer to your question!