# Curly Brakets in Es2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, brackets

I was reading some tweets and I came across [this tweet by Dan Abromov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/642448853556441092/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

The syntax has me confused.

```
const Font = ({ children }) => 
 <Block...
```

What is the point of **{ }** around children? Clearly its not an object. I presume its ES2015 feature.

Many thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: seems like half the new shortcuts look like syntax errors...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a destructuring binding pattern. It indicates that the parameter `children` should be bound to the value of the `children` property of an object passed to the function.

Try this in an ES2015 environment:

```
function x({ foo }) {
  console.log(foo);
}

x({ hello: "world", foo: "bar", well: "that's all"});
```

The string "bar" will be logged to the console, because that's the value of the "foo" property of the object passed to the function.

If the value passed to the function is an object with no "children" property, of if it's not an object at all, then the parameter will be `undefined`.